# Lazyfoo SDL2/GLSL code shows black screen on OS X only

Tags: macos, opengl, glsl, sdl, sdl-2

SCROLL TO BOTTOM FOR SOLUTION

I've seen several similar questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630096/only-glsl-shader-version-120-works-on-mac-os-x) being the closest), but haven't found an answer. I've got some code that I've run successfully on Windows and Linux, but when I run it on OS X (10.9, Mavericks) I just get a black screen.

I'm directly copying the 51st SDL2 Tutorial from Lazyfoo, [found here](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/51_SDL_and_modern_opengl/index.php) (with source at the bottom of the page).

The only changes I've made to his code are to fix certain includes:

```
#include <SDL.h> ==> #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <gl\glew.h> ==> #include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h> ==> #include <SDL2/SDL_opengl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h> ==> #include <OpenGL/glu.h>
```

I compile the program with g++, which I got off brew (4.9)

```
g++ 51_SDL_and_modern_opengl.cpp -lSDL2 -lGLEW -framework OpenGL
```

I have several suspicions as to the problem:

1. I'm using SDL2 (downloaded from brew)'s OpenGL header. I got GLEW of brew as well, but I'm using Apple's default glu.
2. My version of OS X can't handle OpenGL 3.3, or it wants 3.2

As to the second one, the output from glGetString(GL_VERSION) and glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) are:

GL version: 3.3 NVIDIA-8.24.16 310.90.9.05f01

GLSL version: 3.30

I tried switching the minor version in the SDL call to 2, but that didn't fix it. I also tried changing the version to #version 330 rather than #version 140, but still nothing.

By nothing I mean that I get a black screen, but the program compiles. For the record, what I'm expecting from that sample is a white square. Lazyfoo has a tutorial (the previous one, number 50) in which he uses OpenGL 2.1 to draw a white square, and that code runs as expected on the Apple machine.

Any help is appreciated. I'm debating asking Lazyfoo himself, but it seems to be something he's working on at the moment.

**ANSWER**

Thank you to Reto Koradi for the answer - apparently the core profile requires the use of Vertex Array Objects. I got it working by changing the code starting around line 180 (and adding a global VAO GLuint):

```
//Create VAO
glGenVertexArrays(1, &gVAO);
glBindVertexArray(gVAO);

//Create 2 buffers (position, indices)
GLuint buffers[2];
glGenBuffers(2, buffers);   

//Create VBO
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 2 * 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( gVertexPos2DLocation );
glVertexAttribPointer( gVertexPos2DLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL );

//Create IBO
glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[1]);
glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(GLuint), indexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Comment: Just a note, in Dec 2021, adding this code fragment does not fix the issue. Also tried updating the shader/fragmentshader program from https://stackoverflow.com/q/48714591/1541769 and fixing up the variable names to match the ones used here don't work either. Compiles fine, runs without error, but black screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tutorial you are trying to use is broken. It creates an OpenGL context with the Core Profile (good!), but the code is not compatible with the Core Profile (bad!).

In the Core Profile, you need to use Vertex Array Objects (VAO). Add these calls early in the code, before making any other vertex state setup calls:

```
GLuint vaoId = 0;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoId);
glBindVertexArray(vaoId);
```

This should get you at least up and running. To use VAOs more nicely, you should move code around, and make calls like `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` and `glVertexAttribPointer()` only once during setup, while the VAO is bound. The state they set will be tracked in the VAO. Then every time you draw, you only need to bind the VAO again to set up all the state.

The best approach might actually be to find a better tutorial.

Comment: I've tried opengl-tutorial.org, but with the same problem. How can I make sure that the functions belong to Core and not Compatibility mode?